# Update single record in nested state object, react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

I am working on a grid structure where user can add sections, sub-sections or items dynamically. I am managing that things in my redux state object. UI of my grid is as following :

[image]

I want to update a single row record instead of reloading whole grid again. For that, whenever user changes any cell value of row i am calling `update-row` api and on success of that i am trying to update that value in reducer using following code.

```
case UPDATE_ORDER_LINES_SUCCESS:
let stateData = state.get(`GridData`);
      const dataIndex = stateData.children.findIndex(
        (listing) => listing.id === action.row.id  // row id which is updated 
      );
      stateData[0].children[dataIndex] = action.row;
      let data = Object.assign(stateData, { children: stateData.children });
      state = state.set(`GridData`, [data]);
```

This code is working fine for first level of children records (as per json object) but problem occur if user update value of nth level children record. How can i update that row record in my redux state ?

My current redux state sample is :

```
    {
  "views": [
    {
      "id": "5e6b8961ba08180001a10bb6",
      "viewName": "house",
      "description": "house view",
      "name": "house",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "5e6b8961ba08180001a10bb7",
          "viewName": "house",
          "sectionName": "Temporary",
          "sectionId": "SEC-02986",
          "description": "Temporary",
          "sequenceNumber": 4,
          "refrenceId": "SEC-02986",
          "children": [
            {
              "id": "5e590df71bbc71000118c109",
              "lineDescription": "AutoPickPack01",
              "lineAction": "Rent",
              "quantity": 5,
              "deliveryDate": "2020-02-29T06:00:00+11:00",
              "pickDate": "2020-02-28T06:00:00+11:00",
              "pickupDate": "2020-03-01T06:00:00+11:00",
              "prepDate": "2020-02-28T06:00:00+11:00",
              "returnDate": "2020-03-01T06:00:00+11:00",
              "shippingDate": "2020-02-29T06:00:00+11:00",
              "unitPrice": 7000,
              "children": [
                {
                  "id": "5e590df71bbc71000118c10a",
                  "orderId": "Ord-05788_1",
                  "lineNumber": "01a7b77c-792a-4edb-9b73-132440621968",
                  "purchaseOrderNumber": null,
                  "lineDescription": "29Janserial",
                  "lineAction": "Rent",
                  "quantity": 5,
                  "pricingMethod": "Fixed",
                  "displayUnit": "Days",
                  "unitPrice": 0,
                  "chargeAmount": 0,
                  "pickDate": "2020-02-17T06:00:00+11:00",
                  "prepDate": "2020-02-28T06:00:00+11:00",
                  "shippingDate": "2020-02-29T06:00:00+11:00",
                  "deliveryDate": "2020-02-29T06:00:00+11:00",
                  "pickupDate": "2020-03-01T06:00:00+11:00",
                  "returnDate": "2020-03-01T06:00:00+11:00",
                  "name": "29Janserial",
                  "description": "29Janserial",
                  "discountAmount": "",
                  "discountPrice": ""
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What is the best way to update nested children row data in reducer ?

Comment: were you able to find a solution? Please take a look at my answer

Comment: Hi @bsapaka thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As redux doesn't allow to mutate the current state and return it back, it's hard to modify a nested child. Although its highly discouraged to
have this kind of nested structure in redux, rather it should be normalized as **@bsapaka** answered. But if you still want to update the nested
object and return the whole state as an immutable one, `immer` should be your friend. `immerJS` has been so popular for handling immutable states.Although

**Install immer and redux-immer in your case**

`yarn add immer redux-immer`

**In your `reducers.js` file where all reducers have been combined using `combineReducers`**

```
import produce from 'immer';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immer';

// Replace your current combineReducers with
combineReducers(produce, { /* Object of all reducers */ });
```

**In your current reducer file**

```
import product from 'immer';

const findNestedChild = (arr, itemId) => (
  arr.reduce((a, item) => {
    if (a) return a;
    if (item.id === itemId) return item;
    if (item['children']) return findItemNested(item['children'], itemId)
  }, null)
);

case UPDATE_ORDER_LINES_SUCCESS:
  return produce(state, draftState => {
    const { row: newChild, row: { id }} = action;
    let child = findNestedChild(draftState.views, id);
    child = newChild;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should normalize your state, which flattens the tree, and entities become associated by id references instead of direct nesting.

For example

```
{
  "entities": {
    "orders": {
      "o1": { "id": "o1", "productIds": ["p1", "p2"] },
      "o2": { "id": "o2", "productIds": ["p2", "p3"] },
      "o3": { "id": "o2", "productIds": ["p3"] }
    },
    "products": {
      "p1": { "id": "p1", "orderIds": ["o1"] },
      "p2": { "id": "p1", "orderIds": ["o1", "o2"] },
      "p3": { "id": "p1", "orderIds": ["o2", "o3"] }
    },
    "views": {
      "v1": { "id": "v1", "childIds": ["v1.1", "v1.2"] },
      "v1.1": { "id": "v1.1", "parentId": "v1" },
      "v1.2": { "id": "v1.2", "parentId": "v1" }}
  },
  "ids": {
    "orders": ["o1", "o2", "o3"],
    "products": ["p1", "p2", "p3"],
    "views": ["v1", "v1.1", "v1.2"]
  }
}
```

There's more upfront work of finding the correct model and transforming the raw data into it, but you save a lot of time not having to deal with updates that are nested or affect multiple areas of data.

[Redux docs on normalizing](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape/)

[A (de)normalization transformation tool](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr)

[A reducer utility library to manage normalized state](https://github.com/brietsparks/normalized-reducer)